# TFS 2017 - Customize web interface based on security group

Tags: tfs, build, ide, release

I'm struggling with understanding if it is possible to hide certain tabs from TFS web interface based on specific user group. What I'm looking for is to hide Build/Release , Code tabs and if it is possible the configuration option (the gear button). From what I could find there was a "WorkItemOnlyView" default security group in previous versions of TFS that looked like what I wanted. Is it possible to accomplish something like this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make them ["**Stakeholders**"](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/work-as-a-stakeholder) access  which removes their access to code/builds/release entirely in web portal. Then should see the web portal such as below screenshot:

[image]

Another way is [restricting access in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/restrict-access-tfs).

Comment: Yes, that seems to get rid of Code+Builds, but is it possible to disable Configuration? For instance I don't want users to be able to see all the groups and another users.

Comment: @JohnDoe Afraid not able to disable  the configuration page. `Stakeholders can view administrative pages that support managing permissions, area and iteration paths, and more; however, for the most part, they can't modify any objects on these pages.` You could see this in [**Related notes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/get-started-stakeholder#related-notes) part. At least, the user should see the members in his team.